# want to use only integral symbol from amsmath package instead of that from newtxmath

Tags: symbols

Because I loaded `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}` but now I want to use integral symbol only from amsmath instead of that from newtxmath.

I have no clue how to do it.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Please tell us which version of the `newtxmath` package you employ. The reason I ask for this piece of information is that the remedy differs betweens versions of `newtxmath`  up to 1.5 and since 1.5. BTW, version information may be found in the log file.

Comment: @Mico I am using overleaf online, I don't know which version is using for ```newtxmath```, maybe the latest?

Comment: `amsmath` does not provide integral symbols. Do you perhaps mean the integral symbols of Computer Modern fonts (the default you get with no font package)?

Comment: @egreg yes, want to use that default integral symbol, thanks

Comment: Sorry,  I don't use Overleaf.

Comment: @Mico, never mind anyway Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simple enough, because the integral symbols are defined in terms of `\intop` and `\ointop`. You need also to revert the commands for multiple integrals to their `amsmath` version; note that `amsmath` doesn't provide symbols, but just the commands.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

% from fontmath.ltx (CM added to get a fresh name)
\DeclareSymbolFont{CMlargesymbols}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\intop}{\mathop}{CMlargesymbols}{"52}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\ointop}{\mathop}{CMlargesymbols}{"48}
% restore the multiple integrals
\renewcommand{\iint}{\DOTSI\MultiIntegral{2}}
\renewcommand{\iiint}{\DOTSI\MultiIntegral{3}}
\renewcommand{\iiiint}{\DOTSI\MultiIntegral{4}}
\renewcommand{\idotsint}{\DOTSI\MultiIntegral{0}}
%%% end of changes

\begin{document}

\[
\int_{a}^{b} \iint_{\Gamma} \iiint_{\Gamma}
\iiiint_{\Gamma} \idotsint_{\Gamma}
\oint_{\gamma}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Without the added parts you'd get

[image]

If you want less space between the symbols in the the multiple integrals you can add also, before `%%% end of changes`,

```
\makeatletter
\def\intkern@{\mkern-6mu\mathchoice{\mkern-6mu}{}{}{}}
\makeatother
```

[image]

Comment: It works. Thank you so much for the help.